# How to fix ambiguous column reference in Rails has_many through join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following scope:

```
scope :tagged_with, -> (tags) { where(saved_tags: { name: tags }).joins(:saved_tags) }
```

And am running into the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "name" is ambiguous
```

How do I go about specifying that the 'name' is a reference to the SavedTag model in this scope?

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the table name into the query like this:

```
scope :tagged_with, -> (tags) { joins(:saved_tags).references(:saved_tags).where( "saved_tags.name" => tags ) }
```

Note: you should use `references` any time you are directly referencing a table that you are joining in this way.

Comment: I tried this, but I get the following error: 'PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column saved_tags.saved_tags.name does not exist'

Comment: ok, looks like you no longer need the extra "saved-tags", so I've updated my example for you